# python search a text file for a string and add the value to a variable

Tags: python, string, search, copy

I have a text file like this

```
PC Name : Sarah , IP : x.x.x.x
ID : AC:AC LP
PC Name : Moh, IP : x.x.x.x
ID : AC:AC LP
```

I want to SEARCH UP "from the end of the file and up" to find the FIRST Match of the string "AC:AC LP"
then I want to copy the ip in the previous line and add it to a new variable named ip

i searched for codes but they all use normal search and copy the same string , could you help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(in_file) as f:
     lines = reversed(f.readlines()) # start from end of file
     for line in lines:
         if "AC:AC LP" in line: # if AC:AC LP is in the line 
             print( next(lines).rsplit(":",1)[-1]) # go to  next line, split, get ip and break the loop
             break
```

In a function:

```
def find_ip(in_file,sub_s):
    with open(in_file) as f:
        lines = reversed(f.readlines())
        for line in lines:
            if sub_s in line:
                return next(lines).rsplit(":", 1)[-1]
```

If the ip is not always the last element, use re:

```
def find_ip(in_file,sub_s):
    import re
    with open(in_file) as f:
        lines = reversed(f.readlines())
        for line in lines:
            if sub_s in line:
                return re.findall(r"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}",next(lines))[0]
```

Comment: this code will print the value i want to assing it to the variable ip , is this code ok , ip = (next(lines).rsplit(":",1)[-1])

Comment: @MohammedAldaoudi, yes. It will be the first ip up from the line that contains out required substring

Comment: your code was perfect but there is one issue , what i've used is an example and your code split the last : and copy the content . but my program should cut the ip for the line where ever it founded , so could you edit

Comment: what do you mean cut? are you rewriting to another file?

Comment: Now if the line was like that PC IP : x.x.x.x , Name : Sarah  or  PC Name : Sarah , IP : x.x.x.x , Mac : x.x.x.x it will not print the ip address

Comment: The code has printed the ip in thir form ['178.6.137.176'] , while i can't find how to remove the style , I need only the ip

Comment: if you have a list and you want the element inside you index `[0]`

Comment: I changed the code like this  ipp = (re.findall(r"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}",next(lines))[0]) to assign the result to a variable but it didn't work !!